# android video encoding with ffmepg and stagefright

Tags: android, ffmpeg, stagefright

I want to reduce file size that H.264 encoded video file in android.
so i consider two libraries both ffmepg and stagefright.
i need only reduce resolution and bit rate. View point of usage, performance, troubleshooting which one is more good?

Unfortunately, this application support form JB. so I can't use MeidaCodec.